Libre Office is not installable on 24.04 since a few Days
Bei der Installation kommen folgende Meldungen:
[]root@hslstb:/bb/home/wb >apt install libreOffice
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
E: Paket libreOffice kann nicht gefunden werden.
[]root@hslstb:/bb/home/wb >apt install libreoffice
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 libreoffice : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 4:24.8.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1) ist aber nicht installierbar
               Hängt ab von: libreoffice-writer ist aber nicht installierbar
               Hängt ab von: python3-uno ist aber nicht installierbar
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-gnome ist aber nicht installierbar oder
                          libreoffice-plasma ist aber nicht installierbar
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-nlpsolver ist aber nicht installierbar
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-report-builder ist aber nicht installierbar
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-script-provider-bsh ist aber nicht installierbar
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-script-provider-js ist aber nicht installierbar
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-script-provider-python ist aber nicht installierbar
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-sdbc-mysql ist aber nicht installierbar
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql ist aber nicht installierbar
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-wiki-publisher ist aber nicht installierbar
 libreoffice-base : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 4:24.8.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1) ist aber nicht installierbar
                    Empfiehlt: libreoffice-writer ist aber nicht installierbar
 libreoffice-base-core : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 4:24.8.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1) ist aber nicht installierbar oder
                                        libreoffice-core-nogui (= 4:24.8.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1) ist aber nicht installierbar
 libreoffice-base-drivers : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core-nogui ist aber nicht installierbar oder
                                           libreoffice-core ist aber nicht installierbar
                            Empfiehlt: libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb ist aber nicht installierbar
                            Empfiehlt: libreoffice-sdbc-firebird ist aber nicht installierbar
 libreoffice-calc : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 4:24.8.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1) ist aber nicht installierbar
 libreoffice-draw : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 4:24.8.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1) ist aber nicht installierbar
 libreoffice-impress : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 4:24.8.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1) ist aber nicht installierbar
 libreoffice-math : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 4:24.8.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1) ist aber nicht installierbar
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core ist aber nicht installierbar
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
[]root@hslstb:/bb/home/wb >

Wie komme ich weiter
Viele Güße
W.Breitenbach

In English please.  What did you try to do?  If you've got Ubuntu 24.04, Libreoffice come with it.  Are you perhaps trying to do some sort of custom install or maybe trying to install LO on less than a regular supported version of Ubuntu?

Deutsch ; https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/

The version numbers suggest that you are using a non-Ubuntu apt source. Try using packages from the Ubuntu repositories.

Are you using libreoffice fresh ppa?

Please give the output of LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sudo apt update and LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sudo apt install libreoffice. That will temporarily switch the output to English

You said you are running Ubuntu 24.04, but apt is trying to install libreoffice 4:24.8.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1 (notice 22.04). It means, your sources are misconfigured.
First, open Software & Sources, and remove the external source/PPA corresponding to libreoffice.
Run any libreoffice packages installed from the PPA with the commands
sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean

Now, open a terminal, and run sudo apt update
Finally, install libreoffice with sudo apt install libreoffice libreoffice-gtk3.

that worked, libre office is now installed (and the snap version also) snap works but /usr/binsoffice not:/usr/bin/soffice
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::deployment::DeploymentException'
Unspecified Application Error

Canonical publishes the LibreOffice snap package for users who want easy access to the newer versions of LibreOffice from any supported release of Ubuntu.
Uninstalling your existing apt-installed version is not required, though it's up to you to avoid confusing the two versions.
Here, you can see that LibreOffice 24.8.2 is available in the latest/candidate channel:
$ snap info libreoffice
name:      libreoffice
summary:   LibreOffice is a free and open source office suite
publisher: Canonical✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/libreoffice
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bugs?field.tag=snap
license:   MPL-2.0
description: |
  LibreOffice is a free and open source office suite, developed by The
  Document Foundation. The LibreOffice suite comprises programs for word
  processing, the creation and editing of spreadsheets, slideshows, diagrams
  and drawings, working with databases, and composing mathematical formulae.
snap-id: CpUkI0qPIIBVRsjy49adNq4D6Ra72y4v
channels:
  latest/stable:    24.2.6.2 2024-09-10 (326) 1GB -
  latest/candidate: 24.8.2.1 2024-10-08 (330) 1GB -
  latest/beta:      24.2.6.2 2024-09-10 (326) 1GB -
  latest/edge:      ↑                             

So...
$ sudo snap install libreoffice                              // ver 24.2.6

-or-

$ sudo snap install libreoffice --channel=latest/candidate   // ver 24.8.2


+1 for snap. You may want to add sudo? (Or is that not necessary anymore, just like for flatpak?)

@ArchismanPanigrahi good catch! Thanks. Fixed.

I made Upgrade from 22.01 LTS to 24.04 LTS. Maybe that libre office was not uninstalled with tha package ???

Try uninstalling the distribution version and installing the latest stable version of Libreoffice.
You can do this by opening a terminal and:
To remove the version of Libreoffice packaged by the operating system developers, run in a terminal:
 sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice*

Then to download the packages of the latest stable version of Libreoffice, in the terminal you run:
 cd ~/Downloads


 wget https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/24.8.2/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_24.8.2_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz

 wget https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/24.8.2/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_24.8.2_Linux_x86-64_deb_helppack_de.tar.gz

 wget https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/24.8.2/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_24.8.2_Linux_x86-64_deb_langpack_de.tar.gz

Once the packages have been downloaded, to install them you run in that same terminal:
 for x in *.tar.gz; do tar xfv $x; done

 sudo dpkg -i LibreOffice_*/DEBS/*.deb


Why use dpkg instead of apt?

The link in your answer (https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/) does not seem to be official repo of Ubuntu. OP already has issues due to unofficial sources, that is trying to install a 22.04 package into 24.04. It may lead to more disasters. Also, libreoffice installed in this manner may be very hard to uninstall as each individual package would have to be uninstalled separately.

Install the latest stable version of LibreOffice, from The Document Foundation site
